# How to add 2 labels in a chart using vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a chart using vba excel, then accidentally populate a graph that show the user and the counts which I prefer. But stupid of me I forgot to save, due to testing. Now I cant get the logic how to set it again. please  help, thanks

Sample Data

```
Operator  Counts    Team
OPSHAF     123      A
OPSAJC     1245     B
OPSZAL     23       A
OPSJGY     162      C
OPSOSM     54       D
```

[image]

```
Sub CreateChart()

Dim rEmailRng As Range
Dim oEmailCht As Object
Dim cEmailCht As Chart

Dim coEmailCht As ChartObject
Dim iEmailRow As Integer
Dim sEmailSeries As Series
Dim scEmailSerCol As SeriesCollection

On Error Resume Next

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbsh2 = wb.Worksheets("Email")

    Set coEmailCht = wbsh2.ChartObjects.Add(Range("E5").Left, Range("E5").Top, 500, 300)
    coEmailCht = "Email Requests Processed" '& year

    Set cEmailCht = coEmailCht.Chart

    With cEmailCht
        .HasLegend = False
        .HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 50
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1500
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Email Processed by Operator"

        Set scEmailSerCol = .SeriesCollection
        Set sEmailSeries = scEmailSerCol.NewSeries

        With sEmailSeries
            .Name = Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value
            .XValues = Range(Range("A1").Offset(1, 0), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
            .Values = Range(Range("A1").Offset(1, 1), Range("A1").Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown))
            .ChartType = xl3DColumnClustered
        End With

    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome To SO. If Your Objective is that axis label contain Count along with Operator then simply try

```
With sEmailSeries
        '
      .XValues = Range("A2:B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)
```

if you want team name also then

```
.XValues = Range("A2:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
```